# Where is the ♦ Diamond in election page?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, moderators, election

First of all congratulations to all new selected moderators.

We can see that new moderators got their diamond ♦. The respective change we can see in their old posts ( question,answer,comments ). Meaning their old post also contains diamond ♦ besides their profile name. For e.g.

> [image]

But if you visit the [election page](https://stackoverflow.com/election/5) and scroll down then diamond ♦ is missing besides new moderator's profile name. For e.g.

> [image]

If you visit the older election pages then diamond ♦ is present there whoever has got selected in the respective elections.

So, why The diamond ♦ is missing here ?

History repeated again [2015 Moderator Election.](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6)

Comment: Its the **campaign page** right? which is *outdated*, so I don't think it is a bug.

Comment: Well, they do have diamond in the comments...

Comment: @ShadowWizard I already have mentioned `comment` part in the question.

Comment: You mentioned comments in general, I mean in the comments right below the user box that is missing the diamond. Anyway, agree it's a bug, probably oversight of the dev team.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I got your point but if you take comment as old post on that page, then this part is cover in my question.

Comment: @ShadowWizard , Now there is a diamond as expected. I think credit goes to the great great `caching` term.

Comment: Not sure it was caching, more likely they fixed it. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard In that case someone should answer this question.Lets wait for the taker.

Comment: I can't reproduce this.